# Display file content in browser using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, browser

I want to display a file content (HTML file) inside a web page using ASP. I'm trying to display 2 files and show the differences. So i need to color different rows. I tried with TextBox but i can not color a single row. Something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx) but inside a browser. I should be able to easily navigate through rows. (like SetRowColor(rowNumber, color))

Thanks!

Comment: User should be able to edit file in browser and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending you what your after it might work well using tables and nonbreaking rows

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a DataGrid(GridView) and the [valuable information from www.4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304125419/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121504-1.aspx) There you will have row by row edition, and you will be able to save content anywhere. You can split lines from every file in two Datagrids(GridViews), using rows for that purpose. Coloring is really easy. Sure, it all needs work ;)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this by actually doing a HTML encode on the HTML code and display it. Basically you would convert < and > to < and >. then you use a editable Div tag to edit it and save it.

HTH